# excel vba range syntax for summation

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have each L divide by the sum of it's chunk that is separated  by  blank cells.

I am struggling to fix the L2 `SUM($L$2:$L$" & i - 1 & ")"` to L by chunk.
I've tried using `$L$"`: but it says compile error.
The end range of my code is working but not the beginning of the range.
However,when it reaches the next chunk, the first line of it is also not capturing the right end range.

```
Sub Button11_Click()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 3 Step -1
    If Range("G" & i).Value <> Range("G" & i - 1).Value Then Range("N2:N" & i).Formula = "=$L/SUM($L$2:$L$" & i - 1 & ")"
Next i

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt00b.png)

Comment: Well `=$L/` to begin with is problematic, you need the `i` for the row number.

Comment: =$L/ is what I want. My problem is the range in the sum function.

Comment: `=$L/` is not valid though.

Answer (score 0):

### Summing Chunks

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button11_Click()
    
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sCol As String = "G"
    Const dCol As String = "L"
    Const dfCol As String = "M"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Cells(sfRow, sCol).Resize(slRow - sfRow + 1)
    
    Dim crg As Range ' Current Resulting Column Range
    Dim cCell As Range ' Current Cell in Source Range
    Dim fCell As Range ' Current First Cell
        
    For Each cCell In srg.Cells
        If fCell Is Nothing Then
            If Len(cCell.Value) > 0 Then
                Set fCell = cCell
            End If
        Else
            If cCell.Value <> fCell.Value Then
                Set crg = ws.Range(fCell, cCell.Offset(-1))
                crg.EntireRow.Columns(dfCol).Formula = "=" _
                    & fCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Address(0, 0) & "/SUM(" _
                    & crg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Address & ")"
                If Len(cCell.Value) = 0 Then
                    Set fCell = Nothing
                Else
                    Set fCell = cCell
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cCell
    
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        Set crg = ws.Range(fCell, srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count))
        crg.EntireRow.Columns(dfCol).Formula = "=" _
            & fCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Address(0, 0) & "/SUM(" _
            & crg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Address & ")"
    End If
        
End Sub
```